# import certificate using command line in Win XP Home

Tags: windows-xp, certificate

I need to install/import a CA cert (.cer) into the Trusted Root Cert Authorities store of a Win XP ***Home*** using command line. Anyone has any idea which command i can use?

Comment: I don't mind installing other packages...

Comment: Why the command line particularly? Why can't you import using certmgr.msc?

Comment: because i'm creating a script that doesn't require user interaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certutil.exe should do the trick, more details here [in this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934576/en-us?spid=12925&sid=1569). I've only used certutil on Server 2003 and XP Pro but according [to this Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934576/en-us?spid=12925&sid=1569) XP Home is not listed so you may have issues.

If Certutil doesn't work for you you may be able to use a third party tool. [Here's an example of a project](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/internet/security/article.php/c6211) that appears to do this but if there are issues with Certutil working I suspect there may be issues with this too, although you might be lucky.

Comment: I ended up installing Admin pack on a Win XP pro box and copying the following files to the Win XP home box: certadm.dll, certcli.dll, certreq.exe, certutil.exe

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the version of certutil.exe from the Windows Server 2003 Administration Tools Pack.  Also QFE Q329357 is required.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful using -f (force) or you may end up creating duplicate certificate stores.

Answer (score 1):

Using Certutil you can run the following syntax:

```
certutil -f -addstore -enterprise root Certificate_Name.cer
```